# Парсинг тела HTTP-запроса на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, http

Имеется HTTP-запрос, сохранённый в строковой переменной. Например:

```
POST /api/integration/test.json HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.221:1028
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
X-Compress: off
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------16270120918082
Content-Length: 693

-----------------------------16270120918082
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field1"

field1value
-----------------------------16270120918082
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field2"

field2value
-----------------------------16270120918082
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="1.json"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

{
    "ipAddress":"192.168.0.221",
    "port":1028,
}
-----------------------------16270120918082--
```

Вопрос: как в Python распарсить эту строку в какой-нибудь объект, обеспечивающий удобный интерфейс доступа к данным запроса (особенно к телу)?

Я использовал [HttpParser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/http-parser/) когда было достаточно GET-запросов. Модуль хорош для парсинга заголовка, но с телом он практически ничего не делает.

Comment: Английская версия содержит подобные вопросы. Вот примеры, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685217/parse-raw-http-headers и http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214073/parse-raw-http-in-python

Comment: Я бы воспользовался фичами родных модулей urllib и cgi

Comment: на всякий случай упомяну: если этот вопрос как-то относится к вашим предыдущим вопросам об обмене данными между C++  и Python приложениями: вместо посылки строк, содержащих HTTP-запрос, по именованным каналам (named pipe/fifo), можно подключиться по указанному адресу посредством socket API, используя любой C++ http-клиент, а на стороне Питона использовать готовый http-сервер и любой web-framework, который вам нравится. Вот полный пример, используя [flask и mod_wsgi](https://gist.github.com/dAnjou/2874714). Если это перебор, то руками `cgi.FieldStorage()` вызовите, чтобы multipart распознать.

Comment: @jfs это задача выполняется просто в целях саморазвития. Да, все последние вопросы так или иначе связаны между собой) Спасибо за информацию! На данный момент я хочу сделать независимый приёмо-передатчик и скрипт-обработчик, который я бы настраивал на нужный протокол.

Comment: @jfs а можно какой-нибудь пример парсинга? Честно, не смог найти подходящего. Вот есть у меня строка, как в вопросе. Что дальше делать с ней?

Comment: @andreymal взял cgi, но добился чего-то совсем странного. Пошёл через FieldStorage. Он формирует ключи, равные 'name' для первых двух параметров и 'filename' для последнего. Хотя в примерах обычно ключи совпадают со значением name у полей

Comment: @sys_dev содержат, согласен. Не решения как такового нет. В первой ссылке используют deprecated mimetools, а во второй HttpParser, про который я написал в вопросе.

Comment: @AccumPlus: если не получается с помощью `cgi.FieldStorage()` распознать multipart-строку, то задайте отдельный вопрос, специально об этом. Нужно отметить: что распознавание строк, содержащих http запросы достаточно необычно: большинство библиотек в Питоне интегрирует транспорт (IO) и распознавание http (parser) — *напрямую их используйте*. Исключением является [hyper-h2, который реализует http2-протокол на Питоне](http://python-hyper.org/projects/h2/en/stable/). Для [http-заголовков это легко реализовать, например, `mimetools.Message()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4685217/4279).

Comment: @jfs понял, спасибо.

Comment: не обращайте внимание, что mimetools объявлен deprecated, просто развитие функциональности переехало в email пакет. [Решение осталось прежним](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40481308/4279)