# Как декодировать дамп http запроса на питоне?

Tags: python, http

На входе имеем дамп http запроса любого типа.

```
GET / HTTP/1.1[CRLF]
Host: ya.ru[CRLF]
Connection: close[CRLF]
User-Agent: Web-sniffer/1.1.0 (+http://web-sniffer.net/)[CRLF]
Accept-Encoding: gzip[CRLF]
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,UTF-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7[CRLF]
Cache-Control: no-cache[CRLF]
Accept-Language: en;q=0.7,en-us;q=0.3[CRLF]
Referer: http://web-sniffer.net/[CRLF]
[CRLF]
```

Нужно из него получить url, тип запроса, заголовки, декодировать тело, если запрос типа post итд. Из этого всего потом генерируется код, который этот запрос отправляет.

Comment: Распарсить надо, как обычный текстовый файл, потому что это именно он и есть.

Comment: С чем конкретно у вас возникла проблема?

Comment: Похожий вопрос: [Парсинг тела HTTP-запроса на Python](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/573202/23044)

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev с поиском кода который это делает.

Comment: Можно регулярные выражения использовать. На мой взгляд, тут нет необходимости в каких-то библиотеках.

Comment: @SmitJohnth StackOverflow - это не сервис поиска кода. [Ознакомьтесь с правилами.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что это задание, а не вопрос.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev: не вводите людей в заблуждение. Вопрос "как распознать строку, содержащую http заголовок в Питоне" является полезным сам по себе (это актуальная тема, к примеру прочтите [Network protocols, sans I/O](http://www.snarky.ca/network-protocols-sans-i-o)), вне зависимости, что вы думаете о его авторе. У вас неправильное представление о том [как Stack Overflow работает](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/3892/23044). Прочтите: ["Работа за автора"](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/231/23044)

Comment: Хотел ответить @SergeyGornostaev, но за меня уже jfs ответил.

Comment: @jfs я приму к сведению это мнение. Но Stack Overflow - сообщество с саморегуляцией и, судя по реакции, сообществу крайне не нравится информационный шум, создаваемый людьми с клиповым мышлением.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev правильно ли я вас понял, что вы намерены и в дальнейшем оставлять комментарии: *"Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что это задание, а не вопрос."* не смотря на то что подобной причины закрытия не существует—это не моё мнение этот *факт*.  Я дал ссылку, которая  объясняет почему было бы вредно для сайта её заводить—эту часть можно считать (хорошо обоснованным подкреплённым многолетним опытом) мнением. Если вы не согласны (имеете право), то [приведите ваши доводы на Мете с объективными критериями](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/231/23044). Не нужно саботажем заниматься

Comment: @jfs не правильно. Я же написал, что учту ваше мнение. Но  поддерживать своим голосом подобные закрытия скорее всего буду и минусовать подобные вопросы буду.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev почему вы не хотите подробно изложить свою точку зрения на Мете, если вы считаете, что ваши действия не несут вреда сайту (в данном случае я вижу вред, так как вы препятствуете публикации ответов на полезный вопрос (если вы не понимаете тему или вам лично не интересно, это не значит, что у других подобного вопроса нет)). Мне интересно как вы "подобные вопросы" выделяете—какие объективные критерии, если они есть. Какую цель вы хотите достичь? Какие у вас доказательства, что ваши действия ведут к этой цели? Если есть что сказать, опубликуйте ответ на Мете.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev *"Stack Overflow - сообщество с саморегуляцией"* надо понимать как "если наберется 5+ человек с определенным говномнением, они смогут закрывать все вопросы которые им не понравятся"?

Answer (score 1):

Порядок действий будет выглядеть примерно так:

1. Получаем HTTP-запрос.
2. Разбиваем файл с текстом на отдельные строки по символу переноса строки.
3. Складываем получившиеся строки в список.
4. Разбиваем каждую строку на две - до двоеточия и после двоеточия.
5. Формируем словарь, где первая часть строки - ключ, вторая - значение.
6. Конец.

К словарю можно будет обращаться так:

```
http_request["Host"]
```

> 'ya.ru'

Comment: Не, ну руками я бы и сам мог сделать, но хотелось бы использовать готовый модуль - не хочется вникать в потроха http. Вообще я ответ уже нашел, правда, пока только для заголовков, не для тела.

Comment: @SmitJohnth [`h11` модуль, на который я выше неявно сослался](https://github.com/njsmith/h11), поддерживает не только заголовки. В простейшем случае, можно просто передать `sock` объект с `makefile()` методом, который возвращает что-то вроде `io.BytesIO(ваш-http-dump-здесь)`, в `http.client.HTTPResponse`

Comment: @jfs рабочий код выложить можете? Или дать ссылку на него.

Comment: @SmitJohnth для какой конкретно задачи? У h11 модуля есть  examples директория в репозитории. Если для HTTPResponse, то задайте отдельный вопрос, специально о HTTPResponse (на текущий вопрос это не отвечает)

Comment: @jfs для задачи, описанной в вопросе, естественно.

Comment: @SmitJohnth задача в вопросе слишком обширна для меня: одно дело если вы тестируете безопасность сетей, тогда [`scapy` модуль](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/) может быть полезен для составления запросов и анализа ответов. Другое, если http proxy пишете и хотите, содержимое запросов фильтровать/изменять определённым путём (зависит от используемой IO библиотеки, что удобней и как реализовать)...

Comment: ...В третьем, простое `sock.sendall(http_dump)` работает. Если вы пытаетесь тесты для какого-то http-сервера написать, то снова конкретное API может иметь значение (см. `SocketlessRequestHandler` в `test_httpservers.py`). Выше я ссылки привёл, ведущие к [Parse raw HTTP Headers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4685217/4279), что также в некоторых (для заголовков) ситуациях достаточно.

Comment: @jfs не понял про обширность. Мне нужен любой код который декодирует сырой запрос в структуры данных, желательно, конечно, не наколеночный, а из готовой библиотеки.

Comment: @jfs Второй кусок кода отсюда http://stackoverflow.com/a/5955949/2112218, как я понял, не парсит тело запроса. Причем тут socket.sendall() я не понимаю. Я нигде не упоминал что собираюсь отправлять этот запрос. Не надо додумывать того, что не было указано в вопросе.

Comment: @SmitJohnth: *"Я нигде не упоминал что собираюсь отправлять этот запрос."* Из вашего вопроса: *"Из этого всего потом генерируется код, который этот запрос отправляет."*

Comment: @jfs Но не через socket.write же.